# ROR Self Join for self reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am using the Self Joins to add reference to its own table.

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee", optional: true
  has_many :customers
end

class Customer
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

I am fetching the employee data based. One employee will have one employee_head and employee_head will have a boss.

In the serializer i have

```
class EmployeeSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  # include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :id, :name, :manager

  def manager
    ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(object.manager)
  end
end
```

when i query form employee, i am expecting:

```
{
   employee:
      {
           id: 1,
           name: "employee name",
           customer_attributes: [
              { id: 8, name: customer_name }
           ],
           manager: {
                id: 2,
                name: "employee head name",
                customer_attributes: [
                   { id: 8, name: customer_name }
                ],
                manager: {
                     id: 3,
                     name: "boss name",
                     customer_attributes: [
                          { id: 8, name: customer_name }
                     ],
                }
            }
      }
}
```

I am getting the expected data using:

```
Employee.includes(:customers).where(name: "employee name", employee_type: employee)
```

but the problem is when i hit the query, the customer information is fetched from the database multiple time. I am confuse where to use `includes` to avoid N+1 query to DB.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ```Employee.includes(:manager).where(name: "employee name", employee_type: employee)```

Comment: @dbugger i have updated the question, i forgot to add another module. Thanks for the answer. Can you check the question once and help

Comment: Did you try ```Employee.includes(:manager, :customers).where(name: "employee name", employee_type: employee)```

Comment: yes tried it. what happens is that the first level customer_attributes is fetched at one, but the next customers for employee head and boss is fetched individually. That is for every customer in the boss and employee_head list is fetched individually.